# How to make a simple dynamic slideshow/timelapse

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a folder where are saved images from a webcam each X time.

I want to use these image to create a slideshow without transitions effects or music => i want to make a timelaps!

These slideshow must be dynamic (i can use php to build the list of image, each time a user want to watch the "video").

Any sugguestion and code to do this? Javascript? Php? or others??

Thanx!

Comment: Are you wanting the list of images to handle real-time (new images after initial page load), or just page loads `->` show each image sent in the initial request on `X` interval?

Comment: You don't. Just download one of the hundreds of existing scripts that do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the best way i found: simple and speedy

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Video</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY  BGCOLOR="#000000">
<img name="foto">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var Pic = new Array();

Pic[0] = '/images/image1.jpg'
Pic[1] = '/images/image2.jpg'
Pic[2] = '/images/image3.jpg'
//this part in real code is replaced with a PHP script that print image location dinamically

var t;
var j = 0;
var p = Pic.length;
var preLoad = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
preLoad[i] = new Image();
preLoad[i].src = Pic[i];
}
//all images are loaded on client
index = 0;
function update(){
if (preLoad[index]!= null){
document.images['foto'].src = preLoad[index].src;
index++;
setTimeout(update, 1000);
}

}
update();

</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your PHP script send a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag in the heading to reload the page with the latest image after the desired time.

NOTE: There are better, more AJAX-like ways of doing this, but this is the simplest.  Using AJAX to reload just the image and not the whole page would be harder to write but a better user experience.